# flutter http post "type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast"

Tags: rest, http, post, flutter, dart

I am trying to post some data to my backend of this structure:

```
class Activity {
  String id;
  String employeeId;
  String locationId;
  String locationName;
  DateTime startDateTime;
  DateTime endDateTime;
  int breakMinutes;
  String actionId;
  String actionType;
  int startDeviceType;
  int endDeviceType;
  String comment;

  factory Activity.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ActivityFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ActivityToJson(this);
}
```

I am converting the class to a Map like this:

```
Map<String, dynamic> _$ActivityToJson(Activity instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'id': instance.id,
      'employeeId': instance.employeeId,
      'locationId': instance.locationId,
      'locationName': instance.locationName,
      'startDateTime': instance.startDateTime?.toIso8601String(),
      'endDateTime': instance.endDateTime?.toIso8601String(),
      'breakMinutes': instance.breakMinutes,
      'actionId': instance.actionId,
      'actionType': instance.actionType,
      'startDeviceType': instance.startDeviceType,
      'endDeviceType': instance.endDeviceType,
      'comment': instance.comment,
    };
```

... and sending with this lines:

```
Future<HttpError> updateAsync(Activity activity) async {
    var url = '...';

...

    var body = activity.toJson();

    Response response = await http.post(
        url,
        headers: headers,
        body: body,
      );

    if (isSuccess(response.statusCode)) {
      return null;
    }

    return new HttpError(
        errorCode: response.statusCode, errorMessage: response.reasonPhrase);
  }
```

... Then the backend wants to receive those data:

```
{
  "startDateTime": "2019-10-12T19:59:22.801Z",
  "endDateTime": "2019-10-12T19:59:22.801Z",
  "breakMinutes": 0,
  "actionId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
  "startDeviceType": 0,
  "endDeviceType": 0,
  "comment": "string"
}
```

The problem I am facing now is that I get an error when calling post()

`type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast`

If I call `.toString()` on the integer values when casting to a Map, I get `415 - Unsupported Media Type`.

So is this a bug or do I really do something wrong here?

Comment: It is nothing like a bug, it is just that, your backend data supports `string` data, and you're passing `int` to it. It is fine to convert and send it to the backend.

Comment: The backend wants to receive ints, with converting the named values to string I'll get an other error telling me that the values were invalid, so yes, ints are the types I want to send

Comment: Please show the code where you do the conversion from `Map<String, dynamic>` to JSON string. For your debugging purposes, also check that `body` is a `String` and print it.

Comment: I've added more lines of code. Maybe they help finding the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
  var body = activity.toJson(); // here body is still a Map<String, dynamic>
```

to

```
  var body = json.encode(activity.toJson()); // here it's a JSON encoded string
```

Comment: With this method I am getting a 415 - "Unsupported Media Type"

Comment: At least you are now reaching the server. What are your headers?

Comment: the headers are irrelevant cause they actually don't get read. But I can reach the server with other http posts, so this is not an issue, the only problem here are the int values

Comment: I doubt it, as the ints will now be correctly JSON encoded, which you can prove by printing `body` to the console. Are you able to simulate this same post with Postman? Are you including a content-type header?

Comment: Adding "Content-Type" : "application/json" to my header solved this issue, thanks!